# Add numeric values to corrolation levelplot in R

Tags: r, heatmap, levelplot

I would to add values of each small square as in the image below, but I am unsure how this is done. I have the following code, and my dataset is called freqNA0.

```
cp<-cor(data.matrix(na.omit(freqNA0)), method = "spearman")
ord<-rev(hclust(as.dist(1-abs(cp)))$order)
colPal<-colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow"),space="rgb")(100)

levelplot(cp[ord,ord],
          xlab="",
          ylab="",
          col.regions=colPal,
          at=seq(-1,1,length.out = 100),
          colorkey=list(space="top", labels=list(cex=1.5)),
          scales=list(x=list(rot=45),
                      y=list(draw=FALSE),
                      cex=1.2)
)
```

The first image is my plot, and the second is an example of what I would like to have. [My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5tpq.png)

[Example of goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ3uY.png)

Comment: You could try using `library(latticeExtra)` and then add `+ layer(panel.text(x,y,cp[ord,ord]))` after your `levelplot`

Comment: Thank you! I added a round function to the cp[ord,ord], and now it looks very nice!